Limit for a certain amount of records per distinct value for Databricks SQL
It seems so simple, yet I'm stuck.
I want to limit the results that I have to only contain a certain amount of records,say 1000, per distinct value in column A. So for value 1, I need max 1000 returns, for value 2 as well etc.  How do I set my limit clausule in Databricks SQL?



Column A
Column B
Column B




1
Value X
Yes


1
Value Y
Yes


3
Value X
No


2
Value Y
No


1
Value X
Yes


3
Value Y
Yes


2
Value X
Maybe


2
Value Y
Maybe



I've tried  a lot, so far no success.

Use a windows function to achieve this. Change your order by if needed.
select colA, colB, colc 
from (
  select colA, colB, colC, 
    row_number() over (partition by colA order by random()) as rn 
  from your_table
   ) 
where rn <= 1000 

EDIT: Based on comments, you want to filter on some certain values, and, left join. The Order by Random adds lots of time. If you don't need it truly random, then order by something else to significantly reduce your query time.
select colA, colB, colc, colN
from (
  select a.colA, a.colB, a.colC, b.colN, 
    row_number() over (partition by a.colA order by a.colA) as rn 
  from table1 a
  left join table2 b
    on a.colX = b.colY
  where a.colA in (1, 2)
   ) 
where rn <= 1000 


that is correct answer - BUT if you truly need the first x rows for each group (if your table is large and you are looking for efficiency) you need to switch to scripting e.g. pyspark and loop through running a separate sql statement for each group.

@Isolated Thank you. This does seem to work. However when I want to add to the query by expanding to the where clausule by only selecting a subset of values in colA, things seems to get really slow. This is what I did. Is there a way to get the subset where clausule within the brackets as well? Mind you, the query within the brackets is actually a left join of 2 to 3 tables. select colA, colB, colc  from (   select colA, colB, colC,      row_number() over (partition by colA order by random()) as rn    from table1 left join table 2    )  where rn <= 1000 and colA=1 or colA=3

You should put your filter in the subquery, not outer query. Also, the order by random() is a big impact.... if you don't need it random, then change to colA. That's the biggest impact IMO. I'll update the query above with how yours should look.

I also came up with the ORDER BY RANDOM() as the ORDER BY clause of the window function. An ORDER BY is required for the ROW_NUMBER() OLAP function, that's why I also tried it.
Better if you have something in the table to order by to get the n most important rows per Column_A value.
Also - Databricks supports the QUALIFY clause, which lets you avoid nesting two queries for filtering:
WITH
-- your input ...
indata(Column_A,Column_B,Column_C) AS (
          SELECT 1,'Value X','Yes'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'Value Y','Yes'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'Value X','No'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Value Y','No'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'Value X','Yes'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'Value Y','Yes'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Value X','Maybe'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Value Y','Maybe'
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH"
SELECT
  *
FROM indata
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(PARTITION BY Column_A ORDER BY Column_C) <= 2
;




Column_A
Column_B
Column_C




1
Value X
Yes


1
Value Y
Yes


2
Value X
Maybe


2
Value Y
Maybe


3
Value X
No


3
Value Y
Yes




As @Jon mentioned, you can achieve efficiency by using pyspark code and looping through a sql for each group
def limit_rows_per_group(df, group_column, limit):
    groups = df.select(group_column).distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
    limited_dfs = []
    
    for group in groups:
        window = Window.partitionBy(group_column).orderBy(F.col("ColumnB"))
        df_group = df.filter(F.col(group_column) == group)
        
        
        df_group = df_group.withColumn("row_num", F.row_number().over(window))
        df_group_limited = df_group.filter(F.col("row_num") <= limit).drop("row_num")
        
        limited_dfs.append(df_group_limited)
    
    
    result_df = limited_dfs[0]
    for limited_df in limited_dfs[1:]:
        result_df = result_df.union(limited_df)
    
    return result_df

result_df = limit_rows_per_group(df, "ColumnA", 1000)


result_df.show()

